Nuxt 3 Dynamic Routing Conflict with Nested and Single Slug Pages
I am building a project with Nuxt 3, However, I am facing a routing conflict with my current setup. Here is my folder structure:
pages/
  [types]/
    [slug].vue
  [...categoryPath]/
    [slug].vue
  [slug].vue

Requirements:

Product Details Pages: pages/[types]/[slug].vue should handle URLs like /deal/:slug, /voucher/:slug, and /microjob/:slug. Therefore, I would like to restrict [type] to deal, voucher and microjob only.

Blog Posts with Nested Categories: pages/[...categoryPath]/[slug].vue should handle any other nested category paths like /finance/:slug, /finance/markets/:slug, /finance/markets/europe/:slug and so on except for the specified types (deal, voucher and microjob).

Single Slug Pages: pages/[slug].vue should handle single slug pages like /imprint, /privacy-policy, or any other single slug. But that is already the case and no problem at the moment.


Issue:
All routes which have and path like deal/my-slug-12, voucher/my-slug or also market/my-slug as well as finance/my-slug are being handled by pages/[types]/[slug].vue which is wrong. Only paths like starting with deal/..., voucher/... and microjob/... should be handled by pages/[types]/[slug].vue.
If the path is e.g. market/finance/my-slug or has a longer category path like market/finance/europe/germany/my-slug the route is being handled correctly by pages/[...categoryPath]/[slug].vue. But one segment routes are always being handled by pages/[types]/[slug].vue which is wrong as they should only handle routes starting with deal, voucher and microjob.
How can I archive this behavior?
